# Azure devops build pipeline : install npm or angular cli

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to know if I install something like Angular-CLI on the Azure DevOps build Pipeline,  it's going to be installed on my local azure DevOps server?
If the answer is no, so where will it be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding if you are using a self hosted agent then it should be installed in that agent. If you are using Azure's agent which is called Azure Pipelines then it should be installed in that agent.

Refere :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code

Comment: Thanks, it is now clear to me what happens in the build pipeline